# jQuery get() request retrieves data before the new data has been submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

The title may be a bit vague, sorry about that, allow me to explain.

I have a `users_status_likes` table with the follow columns: id, user_id, status_id

The idea is simple, when a user clicks the like button of a status, the data gets submitted to the database with the logged in `user_id` and the `status_id` of the status.

Now, I'm trying to do a `get()` request to retrieve the number of likes a status has. The problem is, the get request is retrieving the number of likes the status had before the new like has been added.

For example, there's a status that has 1 like, but then I click the like button, so now it has 2 likes, there are 2 rows in the table for the same `status_id` but each has a different `user_id`. When I click the like button, the console says `count 1` but it really should be `count 2` because I just liked the status and data has been submitted to the table.

I am using Laravel 5.2, so let me start by posting the route

```
Route::get('likestatusCount/{id}', 'FeedController@getlikesCounter');
```

The `getlikesCounter()` method in `FeedController`

```
public function getlikesCounter($id) {
    $status = Status::find($id);
    return Response::json(['count' => StatusLikes::where('status_id', $status->id)->count()]);
}
```

And the form inside the view

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'FeedController@likeStatus', 'id' => 'like_form', 'class' => 'likeform']) !!}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs like" data-user="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" data-status="{{ $status->id }}" id="like-status">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span class="like-button-text">Like</span> <span class="like-button-counter">({{ $likes_count }})</span>
          </button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The javascript

```
$('.likeform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var submitBtn = $(this).find('.like');
    var likeText = $(this).find('span.like-button-text');
    var likeCounter = $(this).find('span.like-button-counter');
    var status_id = submitBtn.data('status');
    var user_id = submitBtn.data('user');
    var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/socialnet/public/likeStatus',
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { like_status: status_id, user_id: user_id, _token: token },
        success: function(data) {
            submitBtn.removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-danger');
            submitBtn.find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-thumbs-up').addClass('fa-thumbs-down');
            likeText.text('Dislike');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });

    // data.count returns the count before the new like has been submitted
    $.get("http://localhost/socialnet/public/likestatusCount/" + status_id, function(data) {
        likeCounter.text(data.count);
        console.log(data.count);
    });
});
```

Comment: AJAX calls are asynchronous, so if you rely on the response being available for other AJAX calls, you need to place them in the callbacks, success() or error() functions

Comment: If you care about performance and sensible use of resources at all, then you should return that number _in response_ to the POST request that just created a new like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

move this:

```
$.get("http://localhost/socialnet/public/likestatusCount/" + status_id, function(data) {
    likeCounter.text(data.count);
    console.log(data.count);
});
```

inside

```
success: function(data){

}
```